# Crashlytics not giving proper crash reports

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, crashlytics, google-fabric

I am noticing it from my last few build, crashlytics is not sending the proper crash reports...
In crash reports i can not debug on which class the crash occured..

Although I have tried uploading DSYM manually also and using fabric also, I do have followed all the instructions on their website..

I have also tried by uploading DSYM by downloading from itunesconnect but not nothing gives proper crash log

**Sample Crash report**

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException

0  CoreFoundation                 0x18cbcefe0 __exceptionPreprocess

1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18b630538 objc_exception_throw

2  CoreFoundation                 0x18caad200 -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]

3  MyApp                           0x1001a3550 _hidden#4208_ (__hidden#4311_:498)

4  MyApp                           0x10012c008 _hidden#1377_ (__hidden#1463_:318)

5  MyApp                           0x10012f888 _hidden#1403_ (__hidden#1463_:753)

6  MyApp                           0x100132448 _hidden#1497_ (__hidden#1511_:352)

7  MyApp                           0x1001dc1b8 _hidden#5257_ (__hidden#5321_:209)

8  Foundation                     0x18d6c24cc __NSThreadPerformPerform

9  CoreFoundation                 0x18cb7d42c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__

10 CoreFoundation                 0x18cb7cd9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0

11 CoreFoundation                 0x18cb7a9a8 __CFRunLoopRun

12 CoreFoundation                 0x18caaada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific

13 GraphicsServices               0x18e514074 GSEventRunModal

14 UIKit                          0x192d65058 UIApplicationMain

15 MyApp                           0x10018b9cc main (__hidden#3728_:14)

16 libdyld.dylib                  0x18bab959c start
```

Why it is _hidden#4208??

Comment: Did you tried to remove Top builds in top of crashlytics dashboard?

Comment: how should we remove that?

Comment: You can find it on Fabric.io>select app>crashlytics on top of screen

Comment: i have already tried that

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you using Bitcode and sharing your symbol files with Apple? It is it of upmost importance that if you're using Bitcode, that you also share your symbols, otherwise the dSYM doesn't contain useful information.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I have the same issue too. How can we share the bitcode symbols? I use the crashlytics script to upload the build (from Jenkins)

Comment: @MikeBonnell I am not sure about bitcode, archive code from xcode only then i was creating the ipa from that archive using  command line tools, without any flag of bitcode.., so i think bitcodes were not included....
and i have even tried to extract the .xcarchive and then uploaded the dsyms in it but still it didn't worked..
Yes but when i created the ipa from xcode itself still fabric was giving me dsyms missing warning, doesn't mac app automatically upload the dsyms to fabric?

Comment: Normally this is true, but depends on your setup and environment. For example, do you have the run script enabled for all build types? Are you using Static frameworks and not including their symbols?

Comment: yes they were enabled for all the build types..

Comment: @MikeBonnell I still have the issue where the crashes have _hidden entries in it. I have been uploading the dSyms. If I go to the Fabric settings on the website then it tells me that there are no missing dSyms. I even used the upload_symbols script to uploade the dSym files but it doesnt help.

Comment: It's possible you have optional dSYMs that haven't been uploaded. Optional dSYMs are usually .framework dSYMs which we didn't get. When we don't have an Optional dSYM, crashes are still processed and appear in your dashboard, but some frames are not symbolicated. If you upload an Optional dSYM reprocessing of crashes won't happen, but new crashes moving forward will have missing frames symbolicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was, I was creating the build using command line tools and no bitcode flag was used that time for it. so it was giving improper crash reports to me.

Now I include bitcode symbols in my IPA and then after uploading it to appstoreconnect.apple.com if I download the dsym's for my IPA and upload it to crashlytisc's missing dsym section I do get all proper crash reports.

`Note` : I Downloaded the DSYM from the build uploaded to appstoreconnect, as that DSYM includes symbols and only that solved my issue.[image]

Comment: I'm creating the `Archive` & `IPA` with `Xcode`, I always set `Enable Bitcode` `Yes` in `Build Settings` and manually upload missing compressed `DSYM` files from my created `Archive` to `Fabric` missing `DSYM` section, but is not working, I'm always getting `_hidden` in the lines of  Crash Reports. Are you referring to something else?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

1. Goto to **Build Settings**
2. then goto **Build Options**
3. In build options goto **Debug Information Format**
4. and Change **Debug**'s **DWARF** to **DWARF with DSYM File**.

Now again follow Fabric crashlytics steps and you will definitely get the proper crash report.

Refer below screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this Matt's answer on [Xcode Bitcode, Include Symbols settings effect on dSYM generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39853697/4988884)

I've not tried it, but I think by following the guidelines mentioned in Matt's answer you can resolve your query.

Answer (score 0):

finally find exact solution set **Enable bitCode** as a No in build setting

[image]