# iOS Fabric (Crashlytics) showing hidden and missing dSYMS on RELEASE build but works on DEBUG build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm using Xcode 10.2 (Swift 5) and trying to use Fabric (Crashlytics) to catch crash reports on production releases of my app. When I compile as development/debug build I get the full crash report clearly on Fabric but when I archive and then distribute the production release I get missing dSYM error and when I upload the dSYM it shows hidden...

I'm not sure if the issue is because I select "Enterprise" when archiving because this is a company app which is distributed via internal link. I noticed other posts use the Appstore or iTunesConnect which I cannot access due to my limitations.

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1b4968518 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1b3b439f8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1b4872c70 -[NSCache init]
3  UIKitCore                      0x1e10da9c0 -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x1e10db13c -[UITableView _scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:usingPresentationValues:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1e10dafcc -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]
6  Field Services        0x104ea8060 _hidden#2637_ (__hidden#3642_:1502)
7  Field Services        0x104eac634 _hidden#2693_ (__hidden#883_)
8  Field Services        0x104edaf48 _hidden#1384_ (__hidden#883_)
```

---

Let me also mention that when I archive, I select "Enterprise" and these settings:

```
App Thinning: None
Rebuild from Bitcode: YES
Strip Swift symbols: YES
Include manifest for over-the-air installation: YES
```

I have also followed the simple instructions from https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install

```
- Installed via pod (no issues)

- Included API / build key in run script
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" <my-api-key> <my-build-key>

- Added to Input Files
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH)

- Added API Key to Info.plist
  <key>Fabric</key>
  <dict>
    <key>APIKey</key>
    <string>my-api-key</string>
    <key>Kits</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>KitInfo</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>KitName</key>
        <string>Crashlytics</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
```

I have also selected "DWARF with dSYM File" in my Build Options in Xcode..

[image]

I don't know what I'm missing to make this work for production releases..any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode Bitcode, Include Symbols settings effect on dSYM generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843221/xcode-bitcode-include-symbols-settings-effect-on-dsym-generation)

Comment: @MikeBonnell I've read that but does not help...I've followed all those steps and guides... The only difference with my issue is that I do not publish to appstore which i'm thinking might be the issue... I use Enterprise when archiving

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done enterprise distribution in a while. Do you use testflight for that or just host yourself? For builds that go through iTunesConnect you've got to download the symbols after the build is processed and put them on Fabric, from the Activity tab in iTunesConnect. I think once bitcode rebuild kicks in the symbols you originally generated are not useful anymore.

Comment: @FernandoMazzon I don’t use testflight ... I host myself.  I’ve tried so many different combinations with bitcode on/off.. the closest I got was with bitcode off, it shows the function that crashed but also shows compiler line 0 everytime which doesn’t help... struggling with this...

Comment: @rubberchicken Are you still running into this issue?

Comment: @KevinKokomani Yes.

Comment: I don't want to make this an answer since I can't verify that it will help, but take a look, maybe these suggestions help you:

1. Disabling bitcode may help

2. Disabling Swift Symbol stripping may help (unlikely because it looks like you're using ObjC, but not 100% sure)

3. There's more information in this bug that may help: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/10902

Comment: It started working for me after updating Fabric / Crashlytics (I should also mention I'm on Xcode 11.2.1 now)

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it!